# Get number of processor ticks on Mac?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, unix, cpu

How would I find:

- The number of nice ticks
- The number of user ticks
- The number of idle ticks
- The number of system ticks

I am on Mac OS X Snowleopard with an 2.4Ghz Intel Core 2 Duo processor. Is there any way I could get this info?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/101183/what-is-a-cpu-tick

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @DanielBeck I am programming an activity monitor in Objective-C, and need to confirm the validity of stats.

Comment: Do the struct values in `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/sys/proc.h` help? I checked the kernel sources but they aren't provided e.g. as part of the API `sysctl` uses. Search on opensource.apple.com didn't turn up anything else either, the only non-XNU results are in Libkvm and that wasn't anything useful either.

Comment: @DanielBeck Proc.h doesn't help because I need real time values, while Proc.h just provide structures and preprocessor defines. Thank for the help though.

Comment: Are you sure programmatic access of [top output](http://superuser.com/questions/281347/filtering-top-command-output/281654#281654) is not an option?

Comment: You could try to get access to instances of the types defined in `mach/task_info.h`, although some of them only contain relevant values only for *terminated threads*.

Comment: Sounds like a StackOverflow type of question to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Mach to programatically access, since I couldn't find any other method to do so.